# Alternative long form for an acronym in glossaries

Tags: glossaries

How can I make the long form of an acronym as printed in the text differ from the long form displayed in the glossary?

```
\newacronym[plural=AGs,firstplural=Aktiengesellschaften]{AG}{AG}{Aktiengesellschaft \cite{src}}
```

I need the source to be displayed only in the list of acronyms.

## wanted:

GLOSSARY

AG  Aktiengesellschaft (src)

---

### ... in einer Aktiengesellschaft (AG)

mwe:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[acronyms]{glossaries}
\DefineAcronymSynonyms
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
%%% Glossaries/Acronyms
\newacronym[plural=AGs,firstplural=Aktiengesellschaften]{AG}{AG}{Aktiengesellschaft \cite{src}}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Abstract}
... in einer \gls{AG} werden... 
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=List of Acronyms,toctitle=List of Acronyms] 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please add a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/117050)?

Comment: If you have a lot of entries in that form, you could try something like [this example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/cites.shtml) where the citation label is stored in another key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the suggestion from »[Abkürzungsverzeichnis mit glossaries: Ausgabe im Text anders gewollt als im Verzeichnis](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/20496/abkurzungsverzeichnis-mit-glossaries-ausgabe-im-text-anders-gewollt-als-im-verzeichnis)« you could define a command, that results in an output only while printing a glossary but not while using an entry in the text:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[acronyms]{glossaries}
\DefineAcronymSynonyms
\usepackage{glossaries}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeglossaries
%%% Glossaries/Acronyms
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\printglossaryonly}[1]{\unskip}% remove spaces before
\renewcommand*{\glossarypreamble}{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand*{\printglossaryonly}[1]{##1}%
}

\newacronym[plural=AGs,firstplural=Aktiengesellschaften]{AG}{AG}{Aktiengesellschaft
  \printglossaryonly{\cite{knuth:ct}}}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Abstract}
... in einer \gls{AG} werden... 
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=List of Acronyms,toctitle=List of Acronyms] 
\end{document}
```

[image]