# Have different long form for acronym in text and in glossary

Tags: glossaries

I am using the `glossaries` package with the `acronym` option and I would like to have something such as

```
\newacronym{key}{ACRONYM}{in-text long-form}{glossary long-form}
```

in my acronym file, so that in the text, when I use

```
\gls{key}
```

for the first time in the text, the result be

```
in-text long-form (ACRONYM)
```

and in the glossary, this entry shows up as

```
ACRONYM glossary long-form
```

---

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/385390/63689) shows how to add something in the glossary compared to the text, but what if I want two different long forms in the glossary and in the text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the description field. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newacronym[description={All Clever Rigid Nope}]{ac}{ACRN}{Autonomous Conscious Running Node}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
    Blah blah blah \gls{ac} and blah

    \printglossaries    
\end{document}
```

And the result:
[image: Result]